# What is the C#'s bytecode format?

Tags: c#, disassembly, cil

I am trying to intergrate IL disassembler to my disassmbler application([Android-Disassembler](https://github.com/KYHSGeekCode/Android-Disassembler)), but I could not find some libraries that does CIL disassembling.
Therefore, I am trying to develop a simple disassembler for CIL. So I searched over the internet(stack overflow, google, wikipedia, etc). However I could not find out how the CIL assembly code becomes bytecodes.

I opened a C# application in a binary editor, (predicting that I could find human-readable IL source code) but I could only find some binaries inside it.

**How is C# bytecode looks like?**

e.g. X86 instruction bytes have variable lengths:

```
NOP = 0x90,
JMP = 0xEB 0xxx 0xxx 0xxx 0xxx, ...
```

by now, I can only find opcodes for each instructions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions). But I want to know how operands applies with opcodes, too.

(like `88 /r` for `mov`, not only `88`.)

Comment: You should probably look at the [ecma](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) documentation.

Comment: there's the ECMA documentation in the wiki link you posted. And in the table there are already a lot of "targets" after the instruction byte that you can use

Comment: @phuclv Should <method> be String or Number in x6F callvirt <method> ?

Comment: @phuclv And yes, I may be a dumb not to notice that (And in the table there are already a lot of "targets" after the instruction byte that you can use) sorry..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can recommend this book:

**Expert .NET 2.0 IL Assembler** by Serge Lidin

[https://www.amazon.com/Expert-NET-Assembler-Serge-Lidin/dp/1590596463](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596463)

Also **ILSpy** is a very popular open source decompiler:

https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy

Looking around in that source code can probably be enlightening for you.

It seems also that **ILDasm** (the MSIL disassembler that comes with Visual Studio) is open source:

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/tree/master/src/ildasm

Hope some of this can help you.